# How to get the all the mentions using regex from a string without @?

Tags: javascript, regex

I went through many similar related questions but everywhere the result is the value with @ like @xyz. I want value without @.

Currently, I'm using following

```
var str = "xyz xyzxyz xyz @xyzxyz xyz @xyyyz"
str.match(/(^|\B)@(?![0-9_]+\b)([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,30})(\b|\r)/g)
```

It gives me the array of all the mentions like `["@xyzxyz","@xyyyz"]`

How can I just get `["xyzxyz","xyyyz"]`?

Answer (score -1):

On your array, just do

```
var mentions = [];
str.forEach(function(item) {
    mentions.push(item.slice(1));
});
```

That should remove the '@' character from each string.